# What does this green switch with a crystal on Kronos Island do?

Tags: sonic-frontiers

On the western part of the first island, I found a green switch with a crystal on top. When I use the switch it turns blue for a second before turning back to green. What does this switch do?

[image: Green switch]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a set of 3 diamonds in front of the switch. Light up the diamonds to create a path, then hit the switch to generate a grind rail in the same shape. If done correctly, this will let you reach the lower island of the two islands in the water.

[image: Making a grind rail with the switch]

Once you reach the lower island, there's another set of diamonds and a switch you can use to reach the higher island with cyberspace level 1-7.